# Flutter PopupMenu button open URL

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Open an URL by a button from the PopupMenu, is that possible? I search a lot online but i found nothing about that. I did something like that, but unsuccesfully. I dont understand how to use "Hyperlink" from "ulr_launcher" in the "choiceAction" from "PopupMenuButton" i tryid with "NewScaffold" for put a 'body' and a 'child' but got compile error. Here my main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testprj/Constants.dart';
import 'package:testprj/hyperlink.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: choiceAction,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){
              return Constants.choices.map((String choice){
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text(
              'Body',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void choiceAction(String choice){
    Hyperlink('www.test.com', 'sito web',);
  }
}
```

hyperlink.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class Hyperlink extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _url;
  final String _text;

  Hyperlink(this._url, this._text);

  _launchURL() async {
    if (await canLaunch(_url)) {
      await launch(_url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $_url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Text(
          _text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
      )),
      onTap: _launchURL,
    );
  }
}
```

Constants.dart

```
class Constants{
  static const String WebSite = 'WebSite';

  static const List<String> choices = <String>[
    WebSite
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you !

https://dev.to/guimg/hyperlink-widget-on-flutter-4fa5

or

Create two string lists , 1 Website name/visible name and 2 website url

```
List<String> websiteNames =[];
List<String> webUrls =[];

//in the action bar

actions: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton<String>(
            onSelected: launchUrl,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context){
              return websiteNames.map((String choice){
                return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  value: choice,
                  child: Text(choice),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
          )
        ],

//launch method

    launchURL(website) async {
        String url = webUrls[webUrls.indexOf(website)];
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }
```

Comment: The launch method and the two string are to add to hyperlink.dart? And the actions on main.dart? Because i don't understand

Comment: Confirm me one thing, N website names and N URLs ??? Or 1 website name and N URLs ??